# How to run a set of parallel batch files sequentially

Tags: windows, batch-file, parallel-processing, cmd

I am trying to write a test bat file that will do the following:

- Download a file from a server
- Upload a file to the same server

I need three laptops to perform download and upload simultaneously. therefore, I create such a script named 3-chanD.bat:

```
*echo /////////3-channel-Downloading////////
start  cmd.exe /k >time2 timeit chan6D.bat
start  cmd.exe /k >time3 timeit chan11D.bat
start  cmd.exe /k >time1 timeit chan1D.bat*
```

chan6D.bat is basely a script coping file from a server to one of my laptops:

```
*xcopy  "C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Documents\test" "\\192.168.0.102\SharedDocs\test"  /Y /E /S*
```

same as chan1D.bat and chan11D.bat:

```
*echo /////////channel 6 Downloading////////
xcopy  "C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Documents\test" "\\192.168.0.102\SharedDocs\test"  /Y /E /S*
*echo /////////channel  11 Downloading////////
xcopy  "C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Documents\test" "\\192.168.0.104\SharedDocs\test"  /Y /E /S*
```

The upload script does the opposite job.

The problem is I need to sit beside laptops to wait those three laptops complete downloading, then manually run the upload script. I try to write a script:

```
*@echo off
echo /////////3-channel-Downloading////////
call  3-chanD.bat
echo /////////3-channel-Uploading////////
call  3-chanU.bat
pause*
```

but it just run the 3-chanD.bat and 3-chanU.bat in a second. It doesn't wait till download is finished. 
Is there a way to execute a set of commands in parallel, then execute another set of commands in parallel?

Comment: I recommend running the batch files on the client side.  You can have each client wait for a file to exist on the server in order to synchronize the process.  Then as soon as you create the file on the server, each client starts the download and immediately starts the upload once the download finishes.

Answer (score 0):

Have each batch file create a flag file, perform the xcopy, and delete the flag file when the xcopy has finished.

```
type nul > "%temp%\xcopy1.tmp"
xcopy  "C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Documents\test" "\\192.168.0.102\SharedDocs\test"  /Y /E /S
del "%temp%\xcopy1.tmp"
```

Your launching batch file can check for the existence of all three flag files in a loop, and launch the upload processes when they no longer exist.